# one image loads before the rest of the page

Tags: wordpress, loading

I have created a Wordpress theme but am having a problem with the page loading. 
When I move between pages there is one table (with 2 images) in the header that stays behind on the page when all the other elements have been unloaded. 
Any ideas how can I fix this so that this image only shows with the rest of the page?

see http://thetaonline.co.za/newWeb/ and click on each of the menu items to see the image that remains (loads before the rest of the page).

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code is messed up. Its opening a `<table>` before the `<html>` and closing after the `</html>`. This stuff should go inside the `<body>...</body>` area.

Thats basically the reason why its being shown before the page completes to load, because the external resources being called with `<script src=...` or `<link href=...` will hang the page rendering at this point until they are loaded. Thats the reason why this stuff is usually called before everything, inside the `<head>...</head>` block where there is (or should be) still nothing defined for display.

Sinse you are doing it wrong, it will show what is ready for rendering -- basically just that image -- until the rest is loaded.

As of putting the external resource calls inside the `<head>` block, it seems to be correct, so basically you only have to bring that table to the right place to make the page display properly.

I see there are also some typos that may cause issues, like `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US"` missing the `>` in the end etc. You should review your code.

Answer (score 0):

try to use jquery and do something like this:

```
  $(function() {
    $.preload(["image1.png", "image2.png"]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: You should rather take a look at Havenard's answer!

I don't know, if this is a good idea (I guess it is not!), but you could actually hide those images first and then show them with jquery after the page is loaded completely:

```
<table width="35" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display:none" id="specialimages">
<!-- your 2 images in here -->
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#specialimages').show();
});
</script>
```